# Is there a prefix for "infinite"?

Tags: numbers, prefixes, mathematics

I was looking for a prefix I could prepend to a word to mean an infinite amount of the thing the word describes. I eventually found [someone with the same question](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_prefix_for_infinity), and since there were no answers, I offered a "close enough" one. But I got curious and tried to research some more. I didn't find a good list of amount-related prefixes (Wikipedia has an article on [number prefixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_prefix), though), so I [built one](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dRifQE2wSgNyTR6S4sg5ZLu4HgW8NcIHJsSduQGB-yE/edit). But I found no prefix for infinity. Is there one?

Comment: Realistically, apart from some highly abstract concepts like "integers" how many nouns *are* there that you could validly apply this prefix to? The theoretical physicists are already telling us there might not be an infinite amount of time, distance, or mass in the universe. How much else is left?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, in this case I was describing 3D displays, and wanted to make the distinction that some allow only two views (stereoscopic, or, to be more exact, "duoscopic"), others allow multiple (but finite) views, and a third category implements infinite views (at least, for all practical purposes).

Comment: haha I'll buy that. Even if the universe really does turn out to be finite, it can still contain an infinite number of viewpoints (yours and mine are just the beginning of an infinite series! :)

Comment: Well, I guess technically one could argue that, space being quantized, there could only be *n* viewpoints (*n* being an unimaginably large number, of course), times the *m* other points you could be looking at from each of those (*m* being is smaller than *n*-1 because many of those would result in looking at identical directions), which would result in an astronomically large product, but still a finite one :P (though growing, assuming that the universe is expanding).

Comment: Yup - *space being quantized* is the killer there. Even if there [turn out to be 10^500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory_landscape) different "universes", you can't have infinite views. You could have a *lot* - certainly enough for all practical purposes - but if ELU gives you a prefix for "infinite", and I find you marketing some gizmo incorporating it in the product name, I shall sick the [Trade Descriptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_Descriptions_Act_1968) people on you!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Where can I find more information about the prefix ELU? I have the same question?

Comment: @daniel "ELU" stands for "English Language and Usage" (i.e. this site). FumbleFingers was not saying that it is a valid prefix for "infinite", but merely suggesting that such a prefix might be provided here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*infinito-* perhaps?  The OED defines it as:

> combining form from Latin infīnīt-us infinite adj., adv., and n., used
>   in the sense ‘infinitely, to an infinite degree’: as in
>   infinito-infinitesimal

Comment: Woah, infinito-infinitesimal is a word?! Awesome. Anyway, if the suffix is included in the OED, I see no reason not to accept this answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Hmm. I've just checked Google Books. Apart from lots of Italian dictionaries/wordlists, and requotations [of the original?] from David Hartley's 1749 *Observations on Man*, I found only **one** other recorded instance - and that [was from 1880](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22called+the+infinito-infinitesimal%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Besides [we already established](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44755/) that an "infinitesimal" amount isn't even there - you can't have *less than nothing!*

Comment: Wait, what? Should I unaccept the answer (for now at least)? I'm confused.

Comment: It's a valid word which is corroborated by the OED. Whether or not you feel comfortable using it in sentences is a different matter. But it's probably the best and more accurate prefix available for what @Waldir needs. The only other option is to revert to an adjective (infinite, illimitable, immeasurable,  etc.) and avoid using the prefix.

Comment: @Waldir: You must make up your own mind about whether you consider *infinito-infinitesimal* to be a "word". I've provided you with evidence that apart from its apparently first coinage, and one other instance in print 130 years ago, it only really exists as an entry in EOD. I myself do not take it seriously, nor is it clear to me Hartley was using it seriously in 1749 - he seems more to be using it facetiously, as a parallel to his demonstration of the absurdity of a specific line of thought which he's addressing at the time.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, this post is not concerned with the word infinito-infinitesmal - only its prefix. It's a very rare usage, which might discourage you from using it in parlance, but that's your call. But in relation to the question: it's a word which _exactly_ corresponds to what Waldir asked.

Comment: @Jamie: Yes. I'm not taking issue with the prefix itself - although it's obviously very rare, it *is* what OP asked for, and you'd expect most people to understand it in any relevant context. I'm just pointing out to OP that he shouldn't assume *infinito-infinitesimal* is a "word" in the common sense of being something that people actually *use*.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying :) I thought you were referring to the prefix rather than "infinito-infinitesimal". Whether that is a valid word or not would make no difference in the context of the question — it was just a curiosity :)

Answer (score 4):

*omni-* [means "all" or "universally"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/omni-) which isn't exactly infinite, but may be a suitable substitute for some uses.

Classical the Judeo-Christian God is described as omni-potent (all-powerful).

Comment: You might notice that "omni-" was precisely the "close enough" answer I gave to the other guy who asked the same elsewhere, as I mentioned in the details above. I guess I included too many links in there :)

Answer (score 4):

In mathematics, specifically geometry, we use *apeiro-*.

The analog of a pentagon, hexagon, etc. having infinitely many sides is an [apeirogon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apeirogon).

Similarly, a polyhedron with infinitely many sides is an [apeirohedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apeirohedron).

It is from the ancient Greek ἄπειρος, *apeiros*, meaning "infinite" or "boundless" according to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apeiro-).
I surmise this is formed as *a-*, "not," and *peiros*, "bounded," from the same root as *perimeter*, *periphery*, etc.
See also [Apeiron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apeiron_%28cosmology%29) for a little etymology.

Answer (score 1):

Unlimited seems to be a good adjective in the context of the OP's explanation of where this is to be used, i.e. unlimited views or unlimited viewpoints.

Comment: Much clearer than a non-standard or twisted prefix. Depending on the context "limitless" might also be appropriate. But "unlimited number of..." is very clear.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other good answers that "unlimited number of..." is clearer than any alternative, I'd add that a prefix has a strong chance of implying simultaneously. For example, a 3-view display implies that you are seeing three views at once.

You want to describe possibilities, but only one at a time, as far as I can tell.