# Which word (adjective or noun) best describes the idea of doing something anywhere, anytime and with anyone?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

The ideal word, which can be either an adjective or a noun, should describe (or at least allude to) the idea that doing something *anywhere* and *anytime* with *anyone*, or that something is done anywhere, anytime, by anyone.

If no such word exists to satisfy all three above, then a word to satisfy the former two (*anywhere* and *anytime*) is OK too.

**Update:** I agree that some context should be given to better narrow down the choices. I mainly want to describe something (e.g. a service or goods) that would enable people to complete a task or to accomplish some goal anytime and anywhere.

Comment: ML, the best I can think of is "universe", but also "all" could be a good word.

Comment: [indiscriminate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indiscriminate) *Not making or based on careful distinctions; unselective; Unrestrained or wanton; profligate*. As in *"He's an indiscriminate drinker - he'll drink anything with anyone, any time, any place"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's a good one. _Promiscuous_ might work too. The question could use some clarification of context, perhaps using _xxx_ in a sentence.

Comment: @Bradd Szonye: Lots of words "might work" - but as you say, the question lacks sufficient context to make a meaningful choice. To be honest, I'm kinda going off these "single word requests", even though one of them gave me [my most upvoted answer ever](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/44758/2637) (and even then it wasn't the most upvoted answer for the question! :). I just don't see how most such questions improve the site for future visitors.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  Are you trying to get some additional upvotes?

Comment: @rhetorician: Absolutely! Get 'em while they're hot, I say! But I often link to past questions, because I think it's a good way of encouraging people to trawl through the "archives". Probably disproportionately including those asked or answered by me, if only because they come to mind more readily. For example, [here's](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21706/) my ***favourite*** answer (not mine that time, but I did ask the question! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers- I think it was the best answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Profligate works as well, but there's no good single word. It's context-sensitive. The appropriate word might be anything from "slut" to "game" to "eager." I just don't find a single English word encompassing your meaning with precision.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

> [***ready***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ready) :
>    1. prepared mentally or physically for some experience or action
>    2. willingly disposed
>    3. likely to do something indicated
>    4. immediately available

As in ***he's always ready to go***

There's also the more informal

***up for anything***

> I'll do it, you know I'm always *up for anything*.

Answer (score -1):

How about a hyphenated word?  Wide-open.