# "The peasants were the least free of all people, bound by tradition and fettered by superstitions."

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, modifiers, run-on-sentence

Does this sentence need to be broken up by a semi colon, conjuction, or a period? Is there a modifier error here as well?

> The peasants were the least free of all people, bound by tradition and fettered by superstitions.

Answer (score 10):

No, the comma is correct. *Bound...* is a **participial phrase** modifying the subject, *the peasants*, so it is not a clause; normally, only full clauses are set off by a colon, semicolon, or full stop.

As to why you need the comma, a participial phrase that is removed from the subject (or from whatever it modifies) is normally **appositional**, i.e. a kind of grammatical "afterthought", so less tightly connected to it.

Comment: What about a colon?  "... people: bound by tradition, and fettered by superstitions." Is that also correct?

Comment: @DavidM: You could use that, but it looks a little bit less formal/conventional to me. I would probably write *they were bound by...* after a colon. But I think the original version, with the comma, is better.

Comment: I guess my prose style tends to follow my style of speaking.  I'd have a heavier pause than a comma here.

Comment: +1 for deft illustrative use of a semicolon *correctly* in your text!

Comment: @DavidM: Well, nobody is going to come to your house and flog you for a colon! As long as you know what you're doing, you can develop your own style fitting the genre/audience.

Comment: @Cerberus "Please don't flog my colon."  Perhaps we should make T-shirts saying that?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Hah, thanks, I did that without thinking. The result is that I have only a single sentence per paragraph, though.

Comment: @DavidM: Hmm now you're making it sound dirty, yay!

Comment: @Cerberus My pleasure!  (Well, not if someone flogs my colon!)  ;)

Comment: @Cerb: Serendipity rules! (though I much prefer *"Dyslexia lures!"*). I still think it's neat that somebody made an [*infinitesimal change to my answer on the meaning of the word "**infinitesimal**"*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/44758/2637). I think that one *must* have been deliberate on the part of the editor himself, but it was serendipitous that I happened to notice it later when I was editing for some other reason.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Hah, I see it, funny. And I see yet another very, very small edit by Reg...

Comment: @DavidM I would find the colon entirely acceptable (but I'm very fond of colons). A colon would, however, change the aural *rhythm* of the sentence; it introduces a pause equivalent to *videlicet* or *to wit*.

Comment: @StoneyB: I know technically speaking it's not supposed to, but I often find the semicolon makes me pause *more* than a period. When I see it in, say, ELU comments, I think, *"Whoa! This guy's writing **carefully;** I'd better slow up and **read** carefully!"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think you're exactly right. Both a semicolon and a colon indicate that the writer is working in longer, more complex periods - organizing in greater depth.

Answer (score 0):

Cerberus is right on spot, but I see another possible *parse* of the sentence. That would affect whether or not a comma should appear, but for the meaning you intend (and to me the obvious meaning), the comma should in fact be included.

The obvious intent is "The peasants are the least free of all people, {since they are} bound by....

The other possible parse is:

The peasants were the least free of {all people [who are] bound by tradition and fettered by superstitions.}

...in which case the comma would be excluded. However, that would make reading the sentence somewhat difficult and ambiguous.